# Add ken burns effect to supersized gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, image-gallery

i am trying to add a ken burns effect to the supersized gallery. I want simple to add the following code:

```
.image img {
  animation:move 7s ease infinite; /* Change this to alternate to stop the loop. */
  -ms-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
  -0-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation:move 7s ease infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left:-150px;
  top:-150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(0.9); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9); /* Firefox */
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(1.0); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0); /* Firefox */
  }
}
```

Specifically I want to add it to the supersized.css file

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
img { border:none; }

#supersized-loader { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:0; width:60px; height:60px; margin:-30px 0 0 -30px; text-indent:-999em; background:url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;}

#supersized {  display:block; position:relative; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1; height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; 



            }
#supersized img {   width:auto; 
                    height:auto; 
                    display:none; 
                    outline:none;
                    border:none;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    position: relative;


}

#supersized.speed img { -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor; image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; }   /*Speed*/
#supersized.quality img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; image-rendering: optimizeQuality; }           /*Quality*/

#supersized li { display:block; list-style:none; z-index:-30; position:fixed; overflow:hidden; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#111; }
#supersized a { width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
#supersized li.prevslide { z-index:-20; }
#supersized li.activeslide { z-index:-10; }
#supersized li.image-loading { background:#111 url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center; width:100%; height:100%; }
#supersized li.image-loading img{ visibility:hidden; }
#supersized li.prevslide img, #supersized li.activeslide img{ 

}
```

Would be great if someone could help me where to add the code into the .css file or perhaps how to add the ken burns effect in the best way.

Thank you!

Dominik

Comment: maybe you should consider another gallery for this?